# What alternatives are there to SignalR in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, socket.io, signalr

We are using SignalR in our application, and we having some issues with it, such as calls failing and not consistently connecting. So I want to know if there is a good alternative to SignalR that we can use with .NET.  For example, would socket.io be a good option?

Comment: raw websocket calls?

Comment: NodeJS would be an alternative to .NET itself, it's not a websocket library specifically.

Comment: P.s. it sounds more like you've got either network issues or specific problems with your code or server. As far as I know signalr itself is not inherently unreliable. But if you really want to replace it then an alternative based in the .NET world might make more sense. P.P.S asking for product recommendations is off topic on this site unfortunately.

Comment: @CRice may be we can use socket.io instead i did some research and found out that socket.io is easy to use which in turn uses websockets.

Comment: @ADyson hey based in dot net world alternative , that was what i was asking and the issues are specific to signal r not code related, as signal r has some common issues that we can find everywhere on net

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to tell us your sources for that information...it would be best to understand what specific issues you are referring to, then people don't suggest alternatives which might suffer from the same problems. But to be honest it's unclear why you have been unable to research this yourself?

Comment: please refer this link  https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, most of those are not even confirmed by the SignalR team as bugs. People have raised them, but you don't yet know for sure if it's SignalR which is the problem, or something else (either in that person's code, or in a browser or network environment, or an underlying issue with websocket technology - it could be so many things).

Comment: While SignalR is not a guaranteed messaging system (like IBM MQ, etc.), it is highly reliable and persistence of message delivery can be achieved depending on what/how you build. I have several systems delivering dozens of messages every few seconds to hundreds of users without issue. Connection issues, calls failing, etc tend to fall on either a network/firewall/access issue or implementation. Post some issues and code and see if your implementation can be handled better.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about how you want to use Node.js with ".Net"? Node.js is a JavaScript interpreter. If you want to write your backend with Nodejs, you could have a look at socket.io.

If you want to stick with ".Net" you could use Websockets directly, but this would be a little more low level since SignalR bases on WebSockets.

Answer (score 2):

As you are asking for alternatives, I won't go into what you should or should not use. Take a look at this [comparison of frameworks](https://stackshare.io/stackups/pusher-vs-signalr-vs-socket-io).

Also, here is a list of all [realtime backend API](https://stackshare.io/realtime-backend-api) frameworks so take a look and choose what suits your needs the best.

Comment: Stackshare is trash - cannot view anything without signing up first...

Comment: By the time of writing the comment, there were no limitations on viewing the page. I was not aware that the page changed.